# I want to change the drawview every second

Tags: android

I am making a signal light program that changes every second. 
And I am using Canvas. 
The color should change from red to yellow, from yellow to green, from green to red. 
it keeps doing this repeatedly. This is code that does not work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DrawView drawview = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.dv);

    while(true)
    {
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        drawview.color1 = Color.RED;
        drawview.color2 = Color.BLACK;
        drawview.color3 = Color.BLACK;

        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        drawview.color1 = Color.BLACK;
        drawview.color2 = Color.YELLOW;
        drawview.color3 = Color.BLACK;

        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        drawview.color1 = Color.BLACK;
        drawview.color2 = Color.BLACK;
        drawview.color3 = Color.GREEN;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add the code for `DrawView` please. And what does "does not work" mean? What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because you stop your program from working.
When you call `SystemClock.sleep(1000)` from your activity `onCreate` you freeze your app's UI thread, so nothing is displayed on the screen.

If you want your app to automatically do something every second, set up a [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask).

Note however, that this task will run in a background thread, so to update your UI, you will need to use [`runOnUiTHread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

Here is an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Timer drawTimer; //keep your timer, you will need to cancel the task before ending your app

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        drawTimer = new Timer(); //create the timer once your app starts
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        drawTimer.schedule(new UpdateDrawing(), 1000, 1000); //schedule your task to run every second
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        drawTimer.cancel(); //stop the task if app is closed or goes to background
    }

    //here is how your task class would look:
    private class UpdateDrawing extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do color change here
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've been a great help.

Comment: @shH if my solution is working for you, please mark the answer as "Excepted".